# Вопрос по генераторам

Tags: php, генераторы

```
<?php
  function collect($arr, $callback)
  {
    foreach($arr as $value) {
      yield $callback($value);
    }
  }
  $arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
  $collect = collect($arr, function($e){ return $e * $e; });
  foreach($collect as $val) echo "$val ";
?>
```

Не понимаю, для чего нужна переменная `$collect`. Вызывается ли функция-генератор `collect()` при ее присваивании переменной `$collect`? Или она вызывается только при использовании цикла `foreach`?

P.S. Никогда не работал с генераторами.

Comment: В переменную `$collect` помещается результат выполнения функции `collect()`, во время ее инициализации. Ни больше, ни меньше.

Comment: Я так понимаю, что мы это делаем просто для удобства, чтобы не запихивать функцию collect() в цикл foreach()?

Comment: Именно, а еще для того чтобы не городить вызовы на вызове, потому что прежде чем пройтись по массиву, сначала надо будет выполнить функцию. Короче говоря, вроде как экономия памяти (хоть и немного).